# CGRect.init() - Argument labels do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift

I need help solving this error in Swift 3!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLJpb.png)

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 40, 40)) // Create new button & set its frame
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "refresh"), for: []) // Assign an image
barButton.customView = button // Set as barButton's customView
```

Comment: Use autocomplete or check the documentation for available overloads. `CGRect` has no initializer without argument labels, because you need to tell the compiler in what coordinate system/with what units you need the `CGRect` to be initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
CGRect(0, 0, 40, 40)
```

with

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
```

Comment: Thank you this works! I'm new to swift

Answer (score 0):

Use this code-

```
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)) // Create new button & set its frame
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "refresh"), for: []) // Assign an image
        barButton.customView = button // Set as barButton's customView
```

Hope it helps!